# Do I need an SSL cert on my e-commerce store if I use Stripe?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway

I am setting up an e-commerce store using Stripe as the payment system.  From a security standpoint, do I need to use SSL for the rest of the store if the checkout goes through Stripe, which is secured with SSL?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned - our store does not currently do anything with creating an account.  The only part of the site that involves sensitive information is the checkout step, unless the cart is considered sensitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Beside the payment data, the information and password of the user account should be protected too. Without SSL, browser will post username and password to server for identity checking when users login to your site, there are opportunities that data packages might be sniffed by hackers. Although the password had been encrypted, hackers still has a chance to decrypt it. So you must use SSL for the http transfer.

ps: startssl.com provides free level 1 SSL certificates of domain and email.

Answer (score 3):

If you want people to use it you should.  People who know a little bit about security won't even use our site if it doesn't have SSL.  Your users have no idea what is, and isn't protected.  The average user has been trained to look for the little lock (if they've been trained at all).

That said, it's just a good idea to throw ever possible security measure available at an e-commerce site.  You should have SSL for any login anyway.  Even a "reset password" page, in my opinion should be via SSL, because if not, you're giving away one half of the username/password combo to anyone with a sniffer.

An SSL Cert is one of those things that's always worth the investment when the site has anything worth protecting.